# Unable to upload app to iTunes

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, appmobi

I created an iOS app using appMobiXDK. Now to submit app on iTunes Connect I followed all the steps given in "Build for app store" link. I created all the required certificates also got the build. But when I'm trying to submit the build to "Application Loader", I am getting the following error:

> Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple Submission Certificate

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you build your app against the SDK with a distribution cert? Note that an ad hoc cert won't work for submission to iTunes Connect. It needs to be a distribution cert.

Answer (score 0):

We need to create Appstore certificate to submit app to the app store it is present in the distribution tab of developer.apple.com so we need to create it to submit to Appstore.